# .NET KRuntime as a Windows Service?

Tags: .net, windows-services, asp.net-core, kruntime

I can see how to host an ASP.Net application or run a console application with the KRuntime from the samples.

Can the KRuntime be ran as a Windows Service? Do you need to use a Windows Service Wrapper like winsw?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem running an app based on the KRuntime (also known as KRE, XRE, etc.) as a service. You may indeed need to wrap it in some container, but ultimately it's just another program. You won't get any service-aware behavior, such as stop notifications, though. But to just run arbitrary code in a service you don't need that.